# ASP.NET Core SignalR. Ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

Всем привет. Может быть я и задаю много вопросов.
Пытаюсь подключиться к SignalR Hub с SPA-приложения.

```
this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:*****/testhub')
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build()
```

Появляется ошибка:
*Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*

Пробовал так:

```
this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:*****/testhub', {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build()
```

Ошибка:

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:50523/testhub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200*

Использование веб-сокетов в Startup.cs я включил. Пробовал менять версию SignalR в клиентской части, ошибка не исчезает. В многостраничных приложениях все нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. В Startup.cs я передвинул строку UseSignalR над UseMvc.